# Mysql Sort empty value before ORDER BY ASC

Tags: mysql

I have a query result (please refer below)

```
Current Result:
Paid Date
0000-00-00
2010-05-01
2011-06-02
2013-07-08
0000-00-00
```

In this situation I want to show all the unpaid first(with 0000-00-00 stamp) but also I need to achieve something like this result

```
Goal Result:
Paid Date
0000-00-00
0000-00-00
2013-07-08
2011-06-02
2010-05-01
```

What SQL Query I will write to obtain this output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using [**find_in_set**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

Something like.. `ORDER BY find_in_set(date_field, '0000-00-00')`

OR using [**field**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) as  `FIELD(date_field, '0000-00-00') DESC`

Comment: I was about to recommend using a UNION query, but this little gem seems much more reasonable. +1 to you sir

Comment: Perfect that's all I need. This is my encounter with field function Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY (date_column IS NULL), date_column ASC
```

Comment: Sorry I down voted it.. The result of using the query is not what I want. The 0000-00-00 are in the bottom list

Comment: That was to help out. You just need to change ASC to DESC.